# Nav2 multi_tb3_simulation_launch.py - cannot get plugin param value for wait_at_waypoint

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Right now Navigation2 minimal demo of the simulation with multiple mobile robots with Nav2 stacks doesn't seem to work at all.
Every goal is rejected by server, on both robots, every time. I tried to find a bug there but I don't know how to fix it.

I have used:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- ROS2 Galactic (binaries)

Steps to reproduce:

- Source ROS, your workspace and start the script:

`ros2 launch nav2_bringup multi_tb3_simulation_launch.py`

- Click 'Startup' in both RViz for Nav2 stack and set initial poses for both TB3s.
- Try to give any sensible Nav2 goal to `robot1` or `robot2`

#### Expected behavior - similar to these from single TB3 demo:

```
[rviz2-4] Start navigation
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1638358971.369842831] [_]: NavigateToPose will be called using the BT Navigators default behavior tree.
[bt_navigator-11] [INFO] [1638358971.371246080] [bt_navigator]: Begin navigating from current location to (-1.15, -0.68)
[controller_server-8] [INFO] [1638358971.392980651] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[controller_server-8] [WARN] [1638358971.393121450] [controller_server]: No goal checker was specified in parameter 'current_goal_checker'. Server will use only plugin loaded general_goal_checker . This warning will appear once.
[controller_server-8] [INFO] [1638358972.443702721] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[controller_server-8] [INFO] [1638358973.493587536] [controller_server]: Passing new path to controller.
[controller_server-8] [INFO] [1638358973.849973317] [controller_server]: Reached the goal!
[bt_navigator-11] [INFO] [1638358973.881616953] [bt_navigator]: Goal succeeded
```

Chosen TB3 navigates to the goal.

#### Actual behavior

Every goal is rejected by server, on both robots, every time.

```
(...)
[rviz2-4] Start navigation
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1638358155.906285384] [robot1._]: NavigateToPose will be called using the BT Navigator's default behavior tree.
[rviz2-4] [ERROR] [1638358155.908410790] [robot1._]: Goal was rejected by server
(...)
```

When I have tried to find the error source, I have found these lines in terminal log:

```
[waypoint_follower-24] [FATAL] [1642597452.744755801] [robot2.waypoint_follower]: Can not get 'plugin' param value for wait_at_waypoint
[ERROR] [waypoint_follower-24]: process has died [pid 45587, exit code 255, cmd '/opt/ros/galactic/lib/nav2_waypoint_follower/waypoint_follower --ros-args -r __node:=waypoint_follower -r __ns:=/robot2 --params-file /tmp/tmpvn927bmw -r /tf:=tf -r /tf_static:=tf_static'].
...
[rviz2-15] Start navigation
[rviz2-15] [INFO] [1642597504.499973379] [robot2._]: NavigateToPose will be called using the BT Navigators default behavior tree.
[rviz2-15] [ERROR] [1642597504.500514584] [robot2._]: Goal was rejected by server
...
[waypoint_follower-13] [INFO] [1642597516.141306448] [robot1.waypoint_follower]: Configuring
[waypoint_follower-13] [FATAL] [1642597516.153151747] [robot1.waypoint_follower]: Can not get 'plugin' param value for wait_at_waypoint
[ERROR] [waypoint_follower-13]: process has died [pid 45413, exit code 255, cmd '/opt/ros/galactic/lib/nav2_waypoint_follower/waypoint_follower --ros-args -r __node:=waypoint_follower -r __ns:=/robot1 --params-file /tmp/tmpj1a15_ie -r /tf:=tf -r /tf_static:=tf_static'].
...
rviz2-15] Start navigation
[rviz2-15] [INFO] [1642597562.923893887] [robot2._]: NavigateToPose will be called using the BT Navigators default behavior tree.
[rviz2-15] [ERROR] [1642597562.924373425] [robot2._]: Goal was rejected by server
[rviz2-4] Start navigation
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1642597567.179889265] [robot1._]: NavigateToPose will be called using the BT Navigators default behavior tree.
[rviz2-4] [ERROR] [1642597567.180410933] [robot1._]: Goal was rejected by server
```

It seems like something in the `waypoint_follower` isn't configured correctly (plugin param value for `wait_at_waypoint`?).
How should I try to fix it (in the configuration?)?

I asked it a while ago there: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/2719

But I didn't have time to check it closer until now.

EDIT 1:

[image: image description]

Version of my Nav2 packages - everything was installed through `sudo apt-get install ros-galactic-nav2*` - I supposed it was enough to get last. Maybe I was wrong there.

I have used the launch file from `nav2_bringup` called `multi_tb3_simulation_launch.py` without changes. I will compare this version with the newest in the Nav2 repository.

EDIT 2:
The simulation started working after updating in the `nav2_bringup` package on the branch `galactic` the YAML files (`nav2_multirobot_params_1.yaml` and `nav2_multirobot_params_2.yaml` in the folder `params`) with:

```
waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    loop_rate: 20
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"   
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200
```

at the end (similar to the `nav2_params.yaml`).

I guess the binary version installed through `sudo apt-get install ros-galactic-nav2-bringup` has the same incorrect parameters for multi-robot simulation there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394711/nav2-multi_tb3_simulation_launch.py---cannot-get-plugin-param-value-for-wait_at_waypoint/) by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3064 on 2022-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> [waypoint_follower-24] [FATAL] [1642597452.744755801] [robot2.waypoint_follower]: Can not get 'plugin' param value for wait_at_waypoint

Did you provide the `plugin` field? Look at our docs https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/configuring-waypoint-follower.html and migration guides https://navigation.ros.org/migration/index.html. You're probably using an old file on a newer distribution and not paying attention to our library's significant changes.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-01-20**:
I have added in the edit versions of my Nav2 packages - everything was installed through `sudo apt-get install ros-galactic-nav2*` - I supposed it was enough to get newest version. Maybe I was wrong there and it wasn't updated.

I have used the launch file from `nav2_bringup` called `multi_tb3_simulation_launch.py` without changes. I will compare now this version with the newest in the Nav2 repository.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2022-01-20**:
There may be a big in the configs then there - PR would be appreciated if that is indeed the issue!

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-02-08**:
The simulation started working after updating in the `nav2_bringup` package on the branch `galactic` the YAML files (`nav2_multirobot_params_1.yaml` and `nav2_multirobot_params_2.yaml` in the folder `params`), similar to the `nav2_params.yaml`. Full info in the new edit.

I guess the binary version installed through `sudo apt-get install ros-galactic-nav2-bringup` has the same incorrect parameters for multi-robot simulation there.